# Like Button, vBulletin and Mod Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, facebook-like, vbulletin

I'm having a really, really, really weird problem on my vBulletin board using Facebook's Like Button. In my thread template I'm using the following code, which is located inside body tag:

```
<td class="vbs_forumdata alt1">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">(function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs)})(document,"script","facebook-jssdk");</script>
        <div id="thread_sharing_content_facebook">
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="{vb:raw sharingurl}" data-layout="button_count" data-send="false" data-show-faces="false" data-width="90"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

As soon as the template is processed by the vBulletin engine, the variable {vb:raw sharingurl} is replaced by the thread's canonical URL, that looks like this:

```
http://MYDOMAIN/threads/THREADID-THREADTITLE
```

For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/threads/1-Hello-Community
```

Looking at the HTML source of a thread page, everything seems to work as intended:

```
<td class="vbs_forumdata alt1">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">(function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs)})(document,"script","facebook-jssdk");</script>
        <div id="thread_sharing_content_facebook">
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mydomain.com/threads/1-Hello-Community" data-layout="button_count" data-send="false" data-show-faces="false" data-width="90"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

But then, if I click on the Like Button to share the thread page... here comes the drama:

[image: Drama]

The original URL of the thread page is messed up transformed into something like:

```
http://MYDOMAIN/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/THREADID-THREADTITLE
```

Anyone knows why I'm getting that strange problem? The only thing I was thinking about trying to figure it out by myself, is my htaccess file which contains some rewrite rules. It's almost the vBulletin default one... but, anyway, here they are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

// Block Bad Bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} [...]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^forums/.* forumdisplay.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^members/.* member.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^threads/.* showthread.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(?:(.*?)(?:/|$))(.*|$)$ $1.php?r=$2 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

**EDIT: I tried using the Facebook URL debugger and...**

*Scrape Information*

```
Response Code: 200
Fetched URL: http://www.mydomain.com/threads/1-Hello-Community
Canonical URL: http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
```

*Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed*

```
Could Not Follow Redirect Path: Using data from http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community because there was an error following the redirect path.
```

*Errors That Must Be Fixed*

```
Too Many Redirects: URL redirected too many times. Please reduce the number of redirects.
```

*Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed*

```
Admins And App ID Missing: fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
Like Button Tag Missing: og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
Like Button Tag Missing: og:type is missing. The og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
Like Button Tag Missing: og:image is missing. The og:image meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
```

*Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed*

```
Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

*Object Properties*

```
og:url: http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
og:type: website
og:title: #Page Title#
og:image: 
og:description: #Meta Description#
og:updated_time: 1348134967
```

*Redirect Path*

```
originale: http://www.mydomain.com/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
rel="canonical": http://www.mydomain.com/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/threads/1-Hello-Community
```

Final URL is in bold (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata from).

Please, please, PLEASE... help me out!

Comment: Put your URL through the debug tool first, and see what it’s saying. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to add the meta og tag

```
 <meta type="og:url" content="<?php get_current_url(); ?>" >
```

try it